# Como implementar OPEN SSL MDC-2 Hash usando byte Array na entrada de dados

Tags: c

Ola, estou tentando fazer/aprender a como utilizar o openssl MDC-2. 
Encontrei um exemplo (https://linux.die.net/man/3/evp_digestinit) e 
adaptei para tentar entender. Esta funcional para entrada de dados via string (char). 
Preciso que funcione para uma entrada de dados tipo byte array.

Exemplo:
MDC-2 HASH =
000000000000000000000000000000000000AF626E45A45F8AE484DCDB3FF0FBC51B43976F4BFF93E741406CA34622955BE99F6C9C72A32D169423E3EB59D08AF31C2DC06FB16B5DC6BAF23AD4901EBEE6FE9FD145BC706CF43A9556C2B32F1BC5BDA3499B3132A386E14E91B391264B98303DDDA05F2F431D55CBD72235

MDC-2 Resultado =
D247556FE71929C9761F128F7A604CA6

openssl/evp.h

int main()
{

```
EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;
const EVP_MD *md;

char mess[] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
//char mess[] = "";

unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
unsigned int md_len;
//OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

 md = EVP_get_digestbyname("mdc2");

printf("\nOpenssl MDC-2 test\n\n");
printf("String Input....: %s\n\n",mess);

mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);
EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, mess, strlen(mess));
EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);

printf("MDC-2 generated.: ");
for(int i = 0; i < md_len; i++)
    printf("%02X", md_value[i]);

EVP_cleanup();

printf("\n\n\nD o n e !!!\n\n");
getchar();

return(0);
```

}

Desculpem pela formatação.

Comment: Mas o tipo `char` corresponde a 1 byte.

Comment: Sim, mas não posso simplesmente declarar char mess[] = "000000000000000000000000000000000000AF626E4..........72235". Não dá certo.